# Excel Formula for commission paid based on tiered percentage of sale

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Assume the purchase price of a widget is $10,000.00 retail.

commission tiers are as follows:

```
0-54.99% of retail = 0% commission
55% - 59.99% = 2% commission
60% - 64.99 =5% commission
65% (par) pays 10% commission
```

*Plus any % up to 100% of the remaining 35% (65% - 100%) is paid 50% (of the 35%) commission, less $300.

all sales have an admin fee of $300 taken off the sale price, and any financing fees are taken off of the sale price before the admin fee. 
Maximum commission is 24% of retail.

$10,000 
commission would be $3500 - $300 admin = $3200 /2 = $1600 plus
10% of $6500 ($650.) total commission $2250.

Widget is still 10,000 retail, but sell for 
$6,000 commission would be 2% of $5700 (-$300.) Commission $114.

any financing fees are based on a % of total price. (Ranges from 0% - 24%)

Comment: Super User isn't a script writing service. What have you tried so far? Show your working out, and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Im not sure how to show my spreadsheet...

Comment: I am currently using =SUM($G$30*C35)*K43 for example to calculate the 10% commission, then just adding the amount if an overage is there.  sorry if this is too novice of a question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution reaching the same results as in your question.

I used multiple cells to make the formulas simpler, you might combine it into one big formula.

My formulas:

1. `=(D5-D8)/D2` calculates percentage of (sell price minus fee) of the retail price
2. `=IF(G2>0.65,D2*(G2-0.65)*0.5,0)` calculates commission for the part above 65% of retail price
3. `=VLOOKUP(MIN(0.65,G2),A2:B5,2,TRUE)*MIN(0.65,G2)*D2` calculates commission for the part below 65% of commission fee
4. `=G3+G4` calculates total commission

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you... that's exactly what I was hoping for.